# Creative Commons and / or Public Domain library

Tags: ebook, creative-commons

Does anyone know an online library with free books (I mean not "free of charge" but free as a concept) that provides access to e-books published by Creative Commons, Public Domain, etc?

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this.)

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/)? You should read the legalese for copyright issues, though.

Comment: From my (non-lawyerly) reading of the legalese, the only restriction on the books is if you want to distribute them with the 'Project Gutenberg' name attached (and even then, the restriction seems to be just that you have to include the Project Gutenberg boilerplate).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can find free books here:

- [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) - mostly books with expired exclusive copyright, but a few CC-books too (look for Cory Doctorow)
- [Mobileread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/ebooks.php) - again, mostly books with expired exclusive copyright

From both sources you can use and distribute the books without any fees legally in practically all jurisdictions (as copyright is expired based on international treaties).